Mega RAID suddenly, incredible slow after a consistency check and nothing found
I am having difficulty solving this problem. I have a RAID consistency check every Sunday, and I checked today after my colleagues complained about the server being painfully slow. I checked iotop, and it didn't show me any processes that keep hard disks busy. It's a 12-disk plus 1-cascache disk machine. Is there any RAID guru who can solve this problem? I can't seem to find a problem with any of the hard disks. What should I do to bring back the speed? Like before, all the data  seems to be there, sitting perfectly, with just the performance killing us.
Adapter 0 -- Virtual Drive Information:
Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-6, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-3
Size                : 54.575 TB
Sector Size         : 512
Is VD emulated      : Yes
Parity Size         : 10.915 TB
State               : Optimal
Strip Size          : 256 KB
Number Of Drives    : 12
Span Depth          : 1
Default Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAhead, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAhead, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Default Access Policy: Read/Write
Current Access Policy: Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Disabled
Encryption Type     : None
Bad Blocks Exist: No
PI type: No PI

Is VD Cached: Yes
Cache Cade Type : Read and Write


CacheCade Virtual Drive: 1 (Target Id: 1)
Virtual Drive Type    : CacheCade 
Name          : 
RAID Level        : Primary-0, Secondary-0
State             : Optimal
Size          : 148.531 GB
Target Id of the Associated LDs : 0
Default Cache Policy  : WriteBack, ReadAhead, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy  : WriteBack, ReadAhead, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU

This is raid information
/dev/sda4:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 176 MB in  5.18 seconds =  33.97 MB/sec
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            32G   18M   32G   1% /run
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda4        55T  8.1T   47T  15% /
/dev/sda2       2.0G  380M  1.6G  19% /boot
/dev/sda1       511M  5.9M  505M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/loop0      3.9G   11M  3.7G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/0

My file system
[root@server1 home]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test1.img bs=10M count=1 oflag=dsync 
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
10485760 bytes (10 MB, 10 MiB) copied, 4.72906 s, 2.2 MB/s

write test
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,35 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_35], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,36 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_36], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,37 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_37], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,38 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_38], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,39 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_39], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,40 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_40], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,41 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_41], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,42 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_42], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,43 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_43], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,44 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_44], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,45 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_45], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,46 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_46], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,47 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_47], SCSI device
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-4.18.0-513.9.1.el8_9.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Smarttcl all hardisks  Full report all hard disks
https://gist.github.com/danonesyd/9222975e1e4ae4df325fb205814e8b3e
BBU status for Adapter: 0

BatteryType: CVPM02
Voltage: 9406 mV
Current: 0 mA
Temperature: 35 C
Battery State: Optimal
BBU Firmware Status:

  Charging Status              : None
  Voltage                                 : OK
  Temperature                             : OK
  Learn Cycle Requested                   : No
  Learn Cycle Active                      : No
  Learn Cycle Status                      : OK
  Learn Cycle Timeout                     : No
  I2c Errors Detected                     : No
  Battery Pack Missing                    : No
  Battery Replacement required            : No
  Remaining Capacity Low                  : No
  Periodic Learn Required                 : No
  Transparent Learn                       : No
  No space to cache offload               : No
  Pack is about to fail & should be replaced : No
  Cache Offload premium feature required  : No
  Module microcode update required        : No

BBU GasGauge Status: 0x6ff8 
  Pack energy             : 248 J 
  Capacitance             : 111 
  Remaining reserve space : 0 

  Battery backup charge time : 0 hours

BBU Design Info for Adapter: 0

Date of Manufacture: 01/22, 2017
Design Capacity: 288 J
Design Voltage: 9500 mV
Serial Number: 42687
Manufacture Name: LSI
Firmware Version   : 26071-05
Device Name: CVPM02
Device Chemistry: EDLC
Battery FRU: N/A
TMM FRU: N/A
Module Version = 26071-05
  Transparent Learn = 1
  App Data = 0

BBU Properties for Adapter: 0

  Auto Learn Period: 27 Days
  Next Learn time: Sun May 26 13:47:10 2024
  Learn Delay Interval:0 Hours
  Auto-Learn Mode: Transparent

Exit Code: 0x00

BBU info

Is your BBU okay? These are also checked periodically, and if they fail that disables all write caches.

yes bbu seems to be okay I just added info to the question.

This is a low performance design. RAID 6 has worse performance than 5.

but it was 400–500 MB/s before. now it's only (1MB/s -2MB/s)  I tried to copy some backup zip files (30 GB to 50 GB) to another folder. Iotop shows 300-900 MB/s for about 30 seconds, then goes back to 100 KB, waits about 1 minute, then again goes to 300-900 MB/s files, finishing around 15 minutes. really strange behavior and couldn't find a solution.

have you tried to turn it off and on again?

No, I didn't. I only restarted, but I didn't turn it completely off and on. I am afraid the machine will not come online if I do that.

I once had a very bad experience with CacheCade. It suddenly started to behave flaky and then it failed and corrupted the virtual disk, necessitating a downtime and recovery from backups. A cache was two SSDs in RAID1, one of them was found physically dead shortly after; it wasn't worn out and showed no signs of imminent failure when everything happened. In your case, I'd start with detaching the cache and checking it thoroughly. And, by the way, are you using a single SSD for the writeback cache? Don't you think it defeats the purpose of the RAID redundancy in principle?

Unfortunately, it comes only in 12xSAS and 1xSSD148, not by choice. I also suspect that from this intel SSD drive 148GB, do you think detaching cachecade will harm the server?? Or if a single SSD is broken before that, will it be a total catastrophe? or just data, I will lose whatever data cachecade ssd holds at that moment.

yes there is only 1 ssd cache
